SLD styling into GeoServer
I uploaded a SLD styling I made in QGIS into GeoServer, but I keep getting an error that he cant find the column. but GeoServer that the column is available.
I also compared the styling with almost the exact same styling for a different gpgk that does work and there is almost no difference.
I also checked if I typed a word wrong or put in a extra space or backspace.
but that is also not the case.
Does anyone have an idea what the issue could be?

For debugging, it would help if you added some screenshots of your geoserver configuration (layer, sld).

GeoServer is case sensitive with property names
